# Disabling rubber band scrolling on Macs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, macos

I am content with my website but it seems that when folks with trackpads on Macs access it the page becomes distorted. I am hoping you can help me in figuring out how to disable or at least minimize the damage when people use the trackpad and scroll from left to right. I believe this effect is called rubber band scrolling.

Our website is ->circahealthcare dot com<-. You will need to visit it on mac and then slide your finger left or right on the trackpad to know what I am talking about.

Is this a client side issue? Or is there anything I can do with CSS/JS/etc to disable this feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I do notice that you have some odd x-axis scrolling, even on Windows.  Try adding to your css:

```
body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and see if that gives you the behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks. I added this, it seemed to sort some things out. Still, when you tap the left arrow key the page moves to the left... but touchpad seemed to be better.

Answer (score 1):

It's native OSX behavior and something you cannot control with client side code. Users can disable this though through terminal on a mac.

See http://lifehacker.com/5909402/turn-off-elastic-scrolling-in-os-x-lion for more info.